# Laravel Raw SQL Query named parameter binding on order by

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Named parameter binding on "order by" is not working on this full raw statement. An error message is not displayed. start and length work.

```
    $sql = "SELECT
                product.id AS 'product-id',
                product.name AS 'product-name',
                product.status AS 'product-status',
                product.ingredients 'product-ingredients',
                product.price AS 'product-price',
                category.name AS 'category-name'
            FROM
                product
            LEFT JOIN
                category ON product.category_id = category.id
            ORDER BY :orderBy
            LIMIT :start,:length";

    return DB::select($sql, [
        'orderBy' => $orderBy,
        'start' => $start,
        'length' => $length
    ]);
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I do not get an error message. The result is not sorted.

Comment: can you show your `$orderBy` contain data??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the underlying PDO statement. You cannot bind table or column names in a query like you can bind values. See this answer:

[Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

You can rewrite your query without raw expressions:

```
return DB::table('product')
           ->select([
               product.id AS 'product-id',
               ...
           ])->leftJoin('category', 'product.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
           ->orderBy($orderBy)
           ->limit($start, $length)
```

If you must use raw expressions, you will have to manually sanitize the order by value and insert it into the query as a string.

Comment: I had already tried the first one. That will not do. The second one works without the errors. ->select('product.id as product-id', ...); ->orderBy($orderColumn, $orderDir)->offset($start)->limit($length)->get(); But why is parameter binding not working with the full raw statement in order by?

Comment: @ThomasMüller I'm not sure, what do you get when you output the sql query? Call `toSql()` on the query builder.

Comment: Can not call `toSql` on the full raw statement.

Comment: @ThomasMüller You should be able to. This doesn't work? `echo DB::select($sql, [...])->toSql()` Are you getting an error?

Comment: Call to a member function toSql() on array. DB::select returns an array.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L307

Comment: @ThomasMüller You're using the database connection directly rather than using the query builder https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L218

Comment: @ThomasMüller I see the problem, the DB facade returns the connection if you call select on it, I was calling table on it. You should be able to use this method to log the queries: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#listening-for-query-events

Comment: Yes, but we are talking about the full raw statement? `DB::table('product')->select()` => query builder. `DB::select($sql)` => connection directly

Comment: That is not possible? But why does it work with the limit and not with order by?

Comment: @ThomasMüller I did some debugging and tracked down the problem: parameter binding works on values, not table or column names. You're not getting an error because `ORDER BY 'column_name'` is valid, but it won't do what you want.